# How to remove style from iframe tag (not inside iframe but inside tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Page on my server has multiple iframe tags with different ID. One iframe tag I added to embed a youtube video. The iframe tag has a style element that gives it 250 width and 250 height that gets added in by a plugin. I want to remove this style that gets added to the iframe so that the youtube video shows in the height and width in the iframe tag from just this specific iframe as there are other iframe tags on the page that have style that should not be touched.

1) Code I am adding (notice width=640 height=390)

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GxTl1Ykbuww?enablejsapi=1&origin=origin-domain.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

2) Code that is on page when loaded with browser (notice that `style="height:250;width:250;"` is added to the iframe tag now, this is the garbage i want to be removed, but only from this iframe tag id

```
<iframe id="player" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GxTl1Ykbuww?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=origin-domain.com" height="390" width="640" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Javascript or Jquery would be nice. But the remove tag in jquery strips styles from every iframe on page.

ideal solution would result in only the iframe with `id="player"` to be changed from 2) above to no longer have the `style=""` or have the style="" but have nothing inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#player').removeAttr('style')
```

should work using the latest jQuery

As an explanation

```
$('#player')
```

targets a DOM element with id='player' (the # targets an id, like the css selector).

```
removeAttr('style')
```

removes the 'style' attribute from the targeted object

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('player').removeAttribute('style')`

I think it is not a case when you should use jQuery or any other JS library

CSS solution: `#player { width: 640px !important; height: 390px !important; }` but using `!important` is bad practise.

Comment: It's bad practice but it's completely valid :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with ,
For style change :
$("#player").css("Height","90");

For attribute change :
$("#player").attr("Height","90");

For inside of iframe tag attribute or style change :
$("#player div").attr("Height","90");
$("#player div").css("Height","90");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#player').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: @DocKuro... was faster, didn't see.

Comment: happens all the time to me too :)